# Transaction check error in installing vim?

Tags: fedora, vim, yum

I recently updated my fedora to 20 and wanted to install vim.but running `sudo yum install vim` returned this error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz from install of vim-common-2:7.4.179-1.fc20.x86_64 conflicts with file from package vim-minimal-2:7.4.027-2.fc20.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Or update your packages first. The `vim-common` you are installing is newer than the `vim-minimal` already installed.

Comment: @Flup thanks! problem solved. You may post you comment as an answer, so I can accept it! :D

Comment: This is actually a [bug in the vim package](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1066983).

Comment: **Beware** - removing `vim-minimal` will also remove `sudo` unless you spot this and cancel the operation - not good for a production server!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Before you remove vim-minimal, login with root user or do: `sudo -s`

After that, remove vim-minimal with the command: `yum remove vim-minimal`

Then you can install vim: `yum install vim` and after that install sudo: `yum install sudo`

Comment: If `sudo(1)` isn't installed, OP can hardly run it...

Comment: @vonbrand sudo is coupled to vim-minimal, so it gets removed as well. If you are root you avoid the catch-22

Comment: I'd like to point out that this situation is bizarre...

Comment: Definitely a good idea to get a root shell before removing vim-minimal. Yes it is a bizarre situation.

Comment: Yikes, this (package management) is one of the biggest reasons I can't bring myself to switch to Fedora from Ubuntu. I just ran into this in Fedora 23 using dnf. I can't believe their dependency resolution is so bad that you have to uninstall sudo first just to install vim!

Comment: This is really odd behaviour considering that (in CentOS 7.3 / yum 3.4.3), yum knows that the 'reason' for installing `sudo` is 'user' (i.e. manually installed), but it still decides that sudo should be removed anyway.  For more detail on 'reason' feature, install `yum-utils` and see [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/563976/79266).

Comment: The `sudo` package requires `/usr/bin/vi`, probably because of `visudo`. Arguably, this should be a recommendation rather than a hard requirement (see [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1328973)). But, the root cause of the problem here is as in the other answers: installing a package from Updates onto a non-updated system.

Answer (score 26):

```
file /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz from install of vim-common-2:7.4.179-1.fc20.x86_64 conflicts with file from package vim-minimal-2:7.4.027-2.fc20.x86_64
```

Both `vim-common` and `vim-minimal` ship a copy of the `vim` man page.
Ordinarily, this does not result in an RPM conflict, since the files
will be identical in both packages.

However, you seem to have different versions of `vim-common` and
`vim-minimal`, so the file is not identical, thus resulting in the
conflict.  Update `vim-minimal` to be the same version as `vim-common`,
and the problem will go away.

```
yum update vim-minimal
```

and then

```
yum install vim-enhanced
```

Comment: thank you! I find this solution safer than the scary removal of 'sudo'  coupled to vim-minimal

Comment: The general rule is: always update to the latest package set before installing anything.

Comment: This should be the selected answer! Safer and cleaner, thank you

Comment: This should be narked as the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

This is still happening in Fedora 23. My solution was to update **both** packages:

```
sudo dnf update vim-common vim-minimal
```

If I tried to update either package separately, I got the conflict. But I was able to successfully update both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `vim-common` package. As for Fedora 26, there's no `vim-common` package, so it's included in `vim-minimal` package instead. Then, you just have to update it with `sudo dnf update vim-minimal` and then you can install `vim-enhanced` (the real package you'll get for `vim` one).