# su authentication failure, sudo missing

Tags: fedora, sudo, package-management

After removing the `vim-minimal` package, because it was conflicting with the GUI Vim I was trying to install, `sudo` has disappeared, and `su` is giving an authentication failure.

```
[portOdin@localhost ~]$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

[portOdin@localhost ~]$ sudo
bash: sudo: command not found...
```

I tried with zsh as well, and also created a new user, though had the same problems.

If I could get `su` working, or if there is some alternative, I could reinstall with `sudo yum install sudo`. I'm using Fedora 20.

Comment: Try giving `su -` .

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119310/transaction-check-error-in-installing-vim

Comment: Try `gksu` if that command is available

Comment: @SHW - unfortunately `gksu` is not included on Red Hat based distros. Don't ask me why, seems like it should be but it just isn't.

Comment: Remember that `su` wants the root password, not your own password like `sudo` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if anyone ends up in a similar situation, you can use `pkexec yum install sudo`. pkexec will let you enter your password in your OS's GUI.

```
  pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user. If
  username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the
  administrative super user, root.
```

This helped:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed

Answer (score 3):

Removing `vim-minimal` was a mistake. If you intend to make use of `sudo` you have to have that package installed on Fedora. You can tell that `sudo` requires it like so:

```
$ rpm -q --requires sudo | grep vim
vim-minimal
```

I'd suggest putting it back, and working around whatever the other issue actually was with `vim`. Fedora has always had excellent support when it came to all the varieties of `vim` and having them installed together.

I'm using F19 and F20  and they both have pretty much all the Vim's installed simultaneously without issues.

```
$ yum list installed | grep vim | expand
vim-X11.x86_64                         2:7.4.179-1.fc19                @updates 
vim-common.x86_64                      2:7.4.179-1.fc19                @updates 
vim-enhanced.x86_64                    2:7.4.179-1.fc19                @updates 
vim-filesystem.x86_64                  2:7.4.179-1.fc19                @updates 
vim-minimal.x86_64                     2:7.4.179-1.fc19                @updates 
vim-vimoutliner.noarch                 0.3.7-3.fc19                    @updates
```

If you know the password to the root account on your system it's a simple run of this:

```
$ su -
```

You're now root and you can re-install `sudo`.

```
$ yum install -y sudo
```

#### But I really want vim-minimal gone

If you're convinced that you want `vim-minimal` removed you can do so using `rpm` in a more surgical way like so:

```
$ rpm -e --no-deps vim-minimal
```

This will remove `vim-minimal` but leave anything that depends on it left intact on the system. This would include `sudo`, which should still be able to function, even with `vim-minimal` absent.

#### References

- [FedoraForums.org - sudo packages requires vim-minimal](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=292058)

Comment: `su -` did not work. Not sure why, but it gave me the same authentication error. I'll try reinstalling `vim-minimal` though. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If `su -` didn't work then you're probably using the incorrect password for the root user.